# PyQt5 repeat code for a number of widget of same type

Tags: python-3.x, loops, widget, pyqt5

really new to programming, python and OOP.

In Python3 and PyQt5, I have a number of objects: QLineEdit(s) defined in Designer and loaded 
with uicload,  I use to get inputs, I found a way to validate them, my list looks like:

```
        self.validatorint = QtGui.QIntValidator()
        self.inputguiwin.annualsalaryinput.setValidator(self.validatorint)
        self.inputguiwin.annualsalaryinput.textChanged.connect(self.check_state)
        self.inputguiwin.annualsalaryinput.textChanged.emit(self.inputguiwin.annualsalaryinput.text())        
        self.inputguiwin.annualsalaryinput.textChanged.connect(self.disablepushButtonOK)

        self.validatordouble = QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.100, 1.00, 2)
        self.inputguiwin.tosaveinput.setValidator(self.validatordouble)
        self.inputguiwin.tosaveinput.textChanged.connect(self.check_state)
        self.inputguiwin.tosaveinput.textChanged.emit(self.inputguiwin.houseinput.text())        
        self.inputguiwin.tosaveinput.textChanged.connect(self.disablepushButtonOK)

        self.validatorint = QtGui.QIntValidator()
        self.inputguiwin.houseinput.setValidator(self.validatorint)
        self.inputguiwin.houseinput.textChanged.connect(self.check_state)
        self.inputguiwin.houseinput.textChanged.emit(self.inputguiwin.houseinput.text())   
        self.inputguiwin.houseinput.textChanged.connect(self.disablepushButtonOK)

        self.inputguiwin.pushButtonOK.setEnabled(False)
```

self.inputguiwin.annualsalaryinput is a QLineEdit Widget in may main GUI inputguiwin,
then I have tosaveinput and  houseinput. The lines above connect the inputs to a function 
that changes the background color of my input when it is validated and re-able my OK PushButton

Thinking about extending the number of inputs I was wondering about a way of iterating the 
four lines of code for all my QLinesEdit widgets.

Now, I dont understand a lot about Python, classes, object and so on. Which is the best or a way to iterate over the 'list' of my widgets ? I mean is there a way to have a list of objects in Python,
what is the best way to iterate over the widgets in my example? at least the ones that will share the same identical QtGui.QIntValidator() type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reduce your code and make it more readable then you will have to use lists and iterate over them:

```py
for lineedit, validator in (
    (self.inputguiwin.annualsalaryinput, QtGui.QIntValidator(),),
    (self.inputguiwin.tosaveinput, QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.100, 1.00, 2),),
    (self.inputguiwin.houseinput, QtGui.QIntValidator(),),
):
    lineedit.setValidator(validator)
    lineedit.textChanged.connect(self.check_state)
    lineedit.textChanged.emit(lineedit.text())
    lineedit.textChanged.connect(self.disablepushButtonOK)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks again I ended up with:

```
input_list_int=[self.inputguiwin.annualsalaryinput, self.inputguiwin.houseinput]
        for i in input_list_int:
            i_inputguiwin=i
            self.validatorint = QtGui.QIntValidator()
            i_inputguiwin.setValidator(self.validatorint)
            i_inputguiwin.textChanged.connect(self.check_state)
            i_inputguiwin.textChanged.emit(i_inputguiwin.text()) 
            i_inputguiwin.textChanged.connect(self.disablepushButtonOK)

input_list_double=[self.inputguiwin.tosaveinput]
        for i in input_list_double:
            i_inputguiwin=i
            self.validatordouble = QtGui.QDoubleValidator(0.100, 1.00, 2)
            i_inputguiwin.setValidator(self.validatordouble)
            i_inputguiwin.textChanged.connect(self.check_state)
            i_inputguiwin.textChanged.emit(i_inputguiwin.text())  
            i_inputguiwin.textChanged.connect(self.disablepushButtonOK)
```

obviously your method is better, I'll try to dig more into lists